# Error creating BlobContext using jclouds in a Spring MVC application

Tags: java, guice, guava, cloudfiles, jclouds

I have a Spring MVC 4.0.1 web application that needs to upload files to Rackspace Cloud Files. I am using Apache jClouds in order to do this. When trying to create the BlobStore using the following code:

```
BlobStoreContext context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("cloudfiles-us").credentials("username","password").buildView(BlobStoreContext.class);
```

I get the following exception:

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) No implementation for com.google.common.base.Supplier<java.lang.String> annotated with @org.jclouds.openstack.swift.TemporaryUrlKey() was bound.
  while locating com.google.common.base.Supplier<java.lang.String> annotated with @org.jclouds.openstack.swift.TemporaryUrlKey()
    for parameter 4 at org.jclouds.openstack.swift.blobstore.SwiftBlobSigner.<init>(SwiftBlobSigner.java:88)
  at org.jclouds.cloudfiles.CloudFilesApiMetadata$CloudFilesTemporaryUrlExtensionModule.bindRequestSigner(CloudFilesApiMetadata.java:101)

2) No implementation for org.jclouds.openstack.swift.CommonSwiftClient was bound.
  while locating org.jclouds.openstack.swift.CommonSwiftClient
    for parameter 4 at org.jclouds.cloudfiles.blobstore.CloudFilesBlobStore.<init>(CloudFilesBlobStore.java:63)
  at org.jclouds.cloudfiles.blobstore.config.CloudFilesBlobStoreContextModule.configure(CloudFilesBlobStoreContextModule.java:64)

3) No implementation for org.jclouds.openstack.swift.CommonSwiftClient was bound.
  while locating org.jclouds.openstack.swift.CommonSwiftClient
    for parameter 0 at org.jclouds.openstack.swift.blobstore.strategy.internal.SequentialMultipartUploadStrategy.<init>(SequentialMultipartUploadStrategy.java:51)
  while locating com.google.inject.Provider<org.jclouds.openstack.swift.blobstore.strategy.internal.MultipartUploadStrategy>
    for parameter 14 at org.jclouds.cloudfiles.blobstore.CloudFilesBlobStore.<init>(CloudFilesBlobStore.java:63)
  at org.jclouds.cloudfiles.blobstore.config.CloudFilesBlobStoreContextModule.configure(CloudFilesBlobStoreContextModule.java:64)

4) org.jclouds.rest.config.SyncToAsyncHttpApiProvider<org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v1_1.AuthenticationClient, A> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.

5) org.jclouds.rest.config.SyncToAsyncHttpApiProvider<org.jclouds.rest.HttpClient, A> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.

6) org.jclouds.rest.config.SyncToAsyncHttpApiProvider<org.jclouds.cloudfiles.CloudFilesClient, A> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.

7) org.jclouds.rest.config.SyncToAsyncHttpApiProvider<org.jclouds.openstack.swift.extensions.TemporaryUrlKeyApi, A> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.

8) org.jclouds.rest.RestContext<org.jclouds.cloudfiles.CloudFilesClient, A> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.

9) No implementation for org.jclouds.location.suppliers.RegionIdToURISupplier$Factory was bound.
  at org.jclouds.cloudfiles.config.CloudFilesRestClientModule$StorageAndCDNManagementEndpointModule.provideCDNUrl(CloudFilesRestClientModule.java:67)

10) No implementation for org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v1_1.suppliers.V1DefaultRegionIdSupplier$Factory was bound.
  at org.jclouds.cloudfiles.config.CloudFilesRestClientModule$StorageAndCDNManagementEndpointModule.provideCDNUrl(CloudFilesRestClientModule.java:67)

11) No implementation for org.jclouds.location.suppliers.RegionIdToURISupplier$Factory was bound.
  at org.jclouds.cloudfiles.config.CloudFilesRestClientModule$StorageAndCDNManagementEndpointModule.provideStorageUrl(CloudFilesRestClientModule.java:76)

12) No implementation for org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v1_1.suppliers.V1DefaultRegionIdSupplier$Factory was bound.
  at org.jclouds.cloudfiles.config.CloudFilesRestClientModule$StorageAndCDNManagementEndpointModule.provideStorageUrl(CloudFilesRestClientModule.java:76)

13) No implementation for org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v1_1.AuthenticationClient was bound.
  at org.jclouds.rest.config.BinderUtils.bindHttpApiProvider(BinderUtils.java:106)

14) No implementation for org.jclouds.rest.HttpClient was bound.
  at org.jclouds.rest.config.BinderUtils.bindHttpApiProvider(BinderUtils.java:106)

15) No implementation for org.jclouds.cloudfiles.CloudFilesClient was bound.
  at org.jclouds.rest.config.BinderUtils.bindHttpApiProvider(BinderUtils.java:106)

16) No implementation for org.jclouds.openstack.swift.extensions.TemporaryUrlKeyApi was bound.
  at org.jclouds.rest.config.BinderUtils.bindHttpApiProvider(BinderUtils.java:106)

16 errors
```

I cannot figure this out, since its pretty much the first line of the example code at this point...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you running jclouds 1.6.x or 1.7.0 with Java 7u51?  If so, you may have encountered  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-427 .  You can work around this by downgrading to Java 7u45 or upgrading to jclouds 1.7.1.

Comment: I am using Java 7u51. That would be it!